# sed regular expression matching more than intended

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

This,

```
echo 'memory-type="3" reference-number="1" crc="0"' | sed 's/reference-number=".*"//g'
```

returns:

```
memory-type="3"
```

I want:

```
memory-type="3" crc="0"
```

What's the reg-ex to accomplish this?

White-space isn't important in the final result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that `.*` matches the longest possible string; in your case:

```
memory-type="3" reference-number="1" crc="0"
                                  ↑-------↑
```

You want it to match only the `1`. 
The simplest way to do this is to match, not any number of any character,
but any number of any character ***except for quote***:

```
$ echo 'memory-type="3" reference-number="1" crc="0"' | sed 's/reference-number="[^"]*"//g'
memory-type="3"  crc="0"
```